# How to prohibit modifying the field of the initialized structure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, struct

When I write some complex code with MATLAB, I want to prohibit modifying the fields of the structure after it is initialized.

For example, I initialize the following struct

```
s = struct('vec', zeros(3, 1), 'val', 1.0)
```

In the following process, I ALLOW modifying the value of fields:

```
s.vec(1) = 1;
s.val    = 2;
```

I want to PROHIBIT modifying the size of the existing field and PROHIBIT adding a new field to the struct.
If I run the following codes, I want it to return error information.

```
s.vec    = zeros(4, 1);
s.mat    = zeros(3, 3);
```

How to realize the above functions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write your own class, `struct` does not have this functionality.

Below is an example, read the comments for more info.

In particular I'm creating a class with the two properties of your example, and adding input validation with `validateattributes` and setter functions. The `validateattributes` function issues descriptive errors without you having to write them.

With the below class saved on your path, you can then run

```
s = myObject('vec', zeros(3, 1), 'val', 1.0);
```

Where `vec` and `val` both default to `NaN` (of the correct size) if not given as inputs. Then you can index like a struct to set the values, e.g.

```
s.vec(1) = 1; % Allowed, s.vec = [1 0 0] now
s.val = 2;    % Allowed
s.vec = zeros(4,1); % Error: Expected input to be of size 3x1, but it is of size 4x1. 
s.mat    = zeros(3, 3); % Error: Unrecognized property 'mat' for class 'myObject'.
```

Full class example:

```
classdef myObject < matlab.mixin.SetGet
    % We have to inherit from the SetGet superclass (could use a "handle"
    % too) to get the setter functions 
    properties
        % Object properties here which can be accessed using dot syntax
        vec
        val
    end
    methods
        function obj = myObject( varargin )            
            % Constructor: called when creating the object
            % Optional inputs for the properties to use name-value pairs
            % similar to struct construction, with default values
            p = inputParser;
            p.addOptional( 'vec', NaN(3,1) );
            p.addOptional( 'val', NaN(1,1) );
            p.parse( varargin{:} );
            % Assign values from inputs (or defaults)
            obj.vec = p.Results.vec;
            obj.val = p.Results.val;
        end
        % Use set functions. These are called when you try to update the
        % corresponding property but allow for input validation before it
        % is stored in the property. 
        function set.vec( obj, v )
            validateattributes( v, {'numeric'}, {'size', [3,1]} );
            obj.vec = v;
        end
        function set.val( obj, v )
            validateattributes( v, {'numeric'}, {'size', [1,1]} );
            obj.val = v;
        end
    end
end
```